# Can I use the multivariate response predictions of some variables as covariates to predict another correlated response?

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, multivariate-regression

I have covariates to predict 3 multivariate response variables, and would like to use those 3 predictions to predict another forth variable that is also correlated with the other variables:

Predicted_E-Sports_Sales = Predicted_NFL_Sales + Predicted_NBA_Sales + Predicted_MLB_Sales

Can one do this without violating some statistical principles?

And which model would you suggest?

The reason being I have covariates to predict the first 3 output variables at the right of the equation, but my best shot at predicting E-Sports Sale are the other 3 variables, and in fact, with the naked eye I can see in the dataset that there seems to be a pattern, namely the more sales in the other 3 the less in the forth sport. Note, this is data from a online gaming company, hence, those 4 sales variables are correlated as customers and their funds are not infinite.

Ideally, I want to predict all 4 of those response variables at the same time, but if it is only possible step-wise (first the 3 on the right of equation) and if that is statistically not problematic, I would conduct that approach.

Note: so far I am considering predicting the first 3 via a vector autoregressive model or something like this https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4065863/

Comment: why not just directly use the covariates you have available to predict Esports sales?

Comment: Unfortunately the covariates that are strictly related to the other 3 sports, unfortunately who plays next monday (example day) is available for every of the sports here, expect for E-Sports. That is by design so, E-Sports is highly dynamic, the winners are determined mostly the day before. I ran a simple linear regression and for example the number of games in a sports like baseball won't cut it being simply not a significant predictor for E-Sports. The sales from the other 3 sports is a significant predictor the question remains how can I predict this jointly.

Comment: If what I suggested is computationally not feasible, is the only solution to search for more covariates, then I could indeed predict all 4 jointy but not with one of them plugged in as a covariate. As far as I know predicting all 4 jointly can be handled by e.g., Gaussian processes.

Comment: I guess what you can do when you have no covariates is turn that one dependent variable E-Sports Sales into an purely autoregressive process with it's own lags being the sole covariates ....